# Setting up Generalized Linear Regression in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, spatial-statistics, statistics, regression, logistic-regression

I am analyzing a series of old canals and I am trying to make the case that these are tied to certain physical characteristics (soil, slope, etc) in the watershed. To check wether or not my hypothesis is correct I need to do some statistical tests. I used the Ripley's K-funtion tool in ArcGIS pro and did show indeed statistical significant clustering.

Now I am trying to use Generalized Linear Regression to prove the link with land. Since (to my understanding) the line-features are not supported in the GLR-tool and the canals starts in other landscape types than their ending ( wetter vs drier, more slope vs less slope, etc) I extracted the beginning and end of each point and added the different landscape variables to the point features. I generated several random points and merged it with the canal points. The random points got value 0 (no canal) and the canal points got value 1( yes canal) since some variance is necessary for the dependent variable. I ran binary GLR and Continuous (just out of curiosity) and the probability, VIF and Jarque-Bera stats are fine, however my adjusted R-squared is only 0,28.

I am assuming this is because with only the points instead of the lines, the link between landscape transitions and the canals is completely lost and the no-canal points are also present in the same landscape though not near the transitions like yes-canal points.

Any ideas on how to remedy this or evaluate my theory?